# IIS couldn't find a valid certificate with subject

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, duende-identity-server

I deploy the ASP.NET Angular SPA template RC2 app with the Identity Server option on my local IIS server. I get below exception. IIS can't access my local certification info.

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 6.0.21.52210
.NET Version: 6.0.0
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=my-subdomain.azurewebsites.net' on the 'CurrentUser\My'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.SigningKeysLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(String subject, String storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, DateTimeOffset currentTime)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.UnnamedOptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.<>c.<AddClients>b__8_1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
```

I created a certificate via

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "my-subdomain.azurewebsites.net" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My"
```

I set my appsettings.json as

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "My",
      "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
      "Name": "CN=my-subdomain.azurewebsites.net"
    },
    "Clients": {
      "MarketPlace": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
```

When I publish this site with the same configuration as folder publish, it works properly. How can I fix the IIS error so it can access the certificate?

Comment: Please use local machine's My store for such certificates. That's the usual place.

Comment: please verify the Certificate on the server where it is being installed, Navigate to IIS -> Server Certificate -> Select The Certificate Details (Issuer Name).

Comment: I imported my certificate to the IIS server certificates section. I used the certificate Subject name. And I also created Self Signed Certificate and I tried to use this again. Both didn't work. I tried to give also IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool and my local users' permission from the local certificates management (Microsoft Management Console) Manage Private Keys tab. But the result didn't change.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide some answer because recently I have encountered the same problem. Answer is based from multiple source, but I will give step by step solution which I think should solve the problem specially for IIS server and Duende Identity Server.

1. First its important to create self signed certificate which you have rightly written but I used LocalMachine also replace "Your Domain" to your domain for  localhost for use "**localhost**" domain.

   `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "Your Domain" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -FriendlyName "test-certificate"`
2. Make sure your appSettings File has these information

   ```
     "IdentityServer": {
       "Clients": {
         "YourClientName": {
           "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
         }
       },
       "Key": {
         "Type": "Store",
         "StoreName": "My",
         "StoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
         "Name": "CN=Your Domain"
       }
   ```

   }
3. Very important that you assign "**IIS_IUSRS**" and "**Network service**" users to access the private keys.
   To do that go to "mmc" console
   `file -> Add/Remove snap in -> choose certificate -> choose local machine/computer -> find your certificate(generated one) -> right click -> manage certificate -> All task -> Add "IIS_IUSRS" and "Network Service" and give Read and Full Control permission`.
4. Now Export your certificate with **private Keys and extended properties**.
5. Now import the same certificate in the IIS server and for your **https binding attach the imported certificate**.

With these steps i was able to resolved the issue. I hope it help someone and save a lot of time for others.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with .NetCore web API (.NetCore 5.0) implemented using CLEAN architecture (CQRS pattern), I needed 2 certificates to run my application.

1. CA issued certificate for external communication outside the scope of the Application Level
2. Self-Signed for communication within the Application Level, for example, communication with other services/class library services or maybe to DB.
   (For internal communication app will look for a certificate created at the Domain level or Server level)

So in the app setting production JSON, we need to point to a self-signed certificate, while publishing in the application in IIS we need to select CA issued certificate from the SSL Certificate dropdown in "Edit Binding" screen.

point 1: CA issued certificate shall be imported to IIS.
point 2: while self-signed shall be present in MMC, personal or root or web hosting, In local machine or current user, the same shall be referred in app setting production JSON.

Clean Architecture:
https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture